# USB drive not detected & not showing up win10

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, troubleshooting, usb-storage

```
Laptop : Asus x541u
OS : windows 10
```

Hey guys,I've been struggling with this issue for a while ! My usb ports are not working I ran the usb troubleshoot but no results "usb controller is in a failed state or is not currently installed"

I tried other drives but nothing happened the weird thing is that when I plug a mouse or a keyboard it's working just fine which made me confused ....

In the device manager -> Universal Serial BUs controller I have 3  devices :

1. Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host controller-1.0 (Microsoft)
2. USB Composite device
3. USB Root Hub (3.0)

and whenever I plug in a drive nothing pops up in the device manager 
Help please T.T

Comment: Did your USB drive appear in other device node? Is it USB 2.0 or 3.0? re-enable it from BIOS.

Comment: Maybe it needs some Updates from Windows. Did you try to use Diskpart (commandLine) to see if the USB's are showed there ? Or the Operating System need to be restarted(because the driver didn't load well).

Comment: I've tried two usb drives 2.0 & 3.0 but nothing showed up :s only mouse & keyboard are working ! how to re-enable it when even BIOS is not detecting it ??

Comment: My OS is updated ! The diskpart command only shows my hard drive :x